# How to print an array of integers

Tags: arrays, int, ascii

I've got a struct which I'm using to emulate a packet, which looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
int source;
int dest;
int type;
int port;
char data[50];
}test;

test packet[50];
```

And I'm trying to print whatever is in the data field to the screen. My current code looks like this:

```
 printf("Enter a series of data numbers from 1-50: ");
    scanf("%c", &packet[i].data[i]);

    while (packet[i].data[i]  > 48 || packet[i].data[i] > 57)
        {
        printf("Data series needs to be between 1-50, try again: ");
        scanf("%c", &packet[i].data[i]);
        }
   printf("%c \n", packet[i].data[i]);
```

By playing around with it I've been able to get it to compile - sometimes it gives me back 402018, sometimes an X and sometimes just skips the code altogether.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I want to print out the entire char array in the current instance of packet[i] (is is incrementing each time a packet is created)

The while statement is to make sure that the char entered is a number, and according to ASCII, numbers are in said range.

Please be gentle with me, I'm very new to this.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Please show the outer loop (where the value of `i` is controlled).  Also you'll want to enter test data via a file, not interactively - programmers don't do data entry! :D

Answer (score 0):

You must use a different loop variable for input of array for that particular packet.
right now , you are using same variable for packet index and character array index that is "i", and instead of "scanf" , I would suggest to use "getche()" function for single charater input.

And also change your while condition to :

```
 while (packet[i].data[x]  >= 48 || packet[i].data[x] <= 57)
```

where "x" is additional loop variable.

```
for(i=0;i<=49;i++)
    printf("Enter a series of data numbers from 1-50: ");
    for(x=0;x<=49;x++){
        packet[i].data[x] = getche();
         printf("%c \n", packet[i].data[x]);
        if(packet[i].data[x]  >= 48 || packet[i].data[x] <= 57)
            {
            printf("Data series needs to be between 1-50, try again: ");
            packet[i].data[x] = getche();

            }
else
{
  break;
}

    }
```

Comment: Also that test in `while` is dodgy; he *might* mean `packet[i].data[i] < 57`, but not sure...

Comment: Sorry yeah that's what I meant for the loop. Also, I'm not taking single character input, it can be up to 50 chars in a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is logically incorrect:

```
while (packet[i].data[i]  > 48 || packet[i].data[i] > 57)
                          ^^                        ^^
```

Change the first `>` to a `<`.

Also you are writing to the ith array member's ith index of data which again looks logically incorrect. You need to maintain two loops one to iterate over the packets and for each packet the inner loop reads data into data array.